# Will it "update" when it "break" from the inner "for" loop in java?

Tags: java

The code shown below is designed to generate 30 different numbers in the range of 36 using nested `for` loop.

This example shows that when it `break` from the inner `for` loop, it would execute the "update" (in this example the "update" is `++i`) in the outside "for" loop. But my teacher told me that it wouldn't.

But when I debug it, it did execute the "update".
Am I correct?

```
public class array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = new int[30];
        for( int i=0;i<a.length;++i)
        {
            a[i] = (int)( Math.random()*36 ) +1;
            for(int j=0;j<i;++j)
            {
                if(a[i]==a[j])
                {
                    --i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for( int num: a) System.out.print( num+" " ); 
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Nikhil This is not a codereview question, he is asking for an explanation, which is on-topic here.

Comment: Oh , i wonder whether i have done sth wrong.I have just started using stackoverflow

Comment: @syndory my bad buddy. Your question is ok.

Comment: @syndory By the way, make sure you always follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names are always written in PascalCase, thus start with uppercase.

Comment: @MCEmperor Thanks for reminding me.I will be careful when i name sth.By the way,does stackoverflow support `markdown`?I notice that my question has been edited.--Oh it does!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That `break` breaks the **inner** loop. The outer loop continues with the update section of the `for` (`++i`). If your teacher told you it wouldn't do that `++i`, he/she is mistaken. The **inner** update (`++j`) is not performed if that `break` is executed, but the outer one is.

Just to be clear we're talking about the same things:

```
int a[] = new int[30];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    // Outer update ----------^^^

    a[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 36) + 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        // Inner update ---^^^

        if (a[i] == a[j]) {
            --i;
            break; // <==== This break
        }
    }
}

for (int num : a) {
    System.out.print(num + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `break` keyword breaks **only** the inner loop, the outer loop still executes as expected and `++i` takes place.

If your teacher said otherwise, he/she probably made a mistake.

Here's another demonstration:

```
//outer loop
for(...){ 

    //inner loop
    for(...){
        if(...){
          break;
        }
    }
}
```

If the condition in the if-body is satisfied, the inner loop breaks **but the outer loop still continues as expected**.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!